# Set php session variable by clicking clicking div

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I am trying to set up a system whereby if a user clicks on a div, a php session variable should be set to the value of another session variable, which has been defined previously.  For example, if a user clicks on the div with id = "game2", $_SESSION['game'] should be set to equal $_SESSION['game2'], which is already defined.

I'm new to ajax and have been having a lot of trouble accomplishing this.  Here is what I currently have:

listofgames.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>    

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function setSessionGame(str){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "setsessiongame.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick = \"setSessionGame(". $_SESSION['game2'] .")\">" ?>
    <div id = "game2"></div>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

setsessiongame.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$q = $_GET['q'];
$_SESSION['game'] = $q;
?>
```

This code has been turning $_SESSION['game'] into an empty string instead of setting it equal to $_SESSION['game2'] when the div is clicked.  I would really appreciate any help fixing my code.

Thanks very much

Comment: where is $_SESSION['game2'] defined?

Comment: It is defined earlier in listofgames.php.  I left out that part for brevity

Comment: What would be a sample value?

Comment: It would be a simple string.  For example, "NFL-NYGDAL"

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are referencing jQuery, you can use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

```
function setSessionGame(str){
    $.get("setsessiongame.php?q="+str, function(data) {
        // ajax complete
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi josh, I tried using $.get() as you described but somehow its still doesn't seem to execute the setsession.php code.  Any idea what the problem might be.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try and make the ajax call in sync but use jquery as you are including it:

```
function setSessionGame(str){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "setsessiongame.php",
        async: false,
        data:  {
            "q" : str   
        },
        success: function(msg) {
        }
    });
)
```

and see if it changes something.

Maybe it could be that the entire querystring is not passed properly.

Mind you this is just a test to try and understand where things are going wrong as your code seems properly formatted.

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately.  I'm pretty confused as to why it's not working.  The setsessiongame.php code doesn't seem to be executing at all.  Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried calling setsessiongame.php?q=something directly to test it? I mean it sounds silly but to test and debug everything has to be tried!